# Higher category's consistency relations

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase, category-theory

I have been reading on higher category and symTFTs. It appears to me that, for higher categories, people seldom mention the consistency relations (like the MacLane coherence theorem in the category case). A few years back, I heard that people didn't even know all the consistency relations for 2-categories.

So, my question is: do we know all the consistency relations for 2-categories now? What about for any $n$-categories?

All comments are welcome! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

MacLane coherence theorem says that any (weak) monoidal category is monoidally equivalent to a strict monoidal category. "Strict" here means the pentagon and unit axioms are equal signs instead of just isomorphisms (which is weak). But since any monoidal category is an one object $2$-category so we can apply the same reasoning and form the **coherence theorem for $2$-category**: any weak 2-category equivalent to a strict 2-category. Where the analogy is by turning the monoidal structure $\otimes$ to composition $\circ$ and we can turn associativity of composition of morphisms into equal signs.

For $n>2$ then we don't have that strong of a statement. For $n=3$ can still make the associativity and unit strict but in this level we have more than just one type of composition and relating them is not "strictifyable". See [Gray category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gray-category).

For $n>3$, I'm not aware/understand of any results but I think there are efforts to continue generalize this using $(\infty,n)$-categories. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0040)

Comment: Ah! I see! Thanks! For the 2-category, is the idea proven? Do you know a reference on it?

Comment: @Waterfall The proof technique is entirely analogous to MacLane coherence theorem but if you want details then [here](https://www.sfu.ca/~khonigs/coherence_essay.pdf) has it (pg. 8-9). Then MacLane coherence theorem becomes a corollary (pg.10)

Comment: Okay, I see. It seems for 2-categories we can prove some coherence theorems. But, we still don't seem to know all the consistency relations (i.e. all the diagrams that commute).

Comment: @Waterfall if you mean a diagram that consists of associator, left/right unit has to commute then it is indeed true for 2-category, see Application 5.1(pg.15) of the same reference. This is not true for 3-category and above though.